# add a row with empty columns to a tab delimited file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have some tab delimited data files with different column numbers. I want to add a header line to these files, the header line only contains 'ID' in the first column, however, the total column number of the header line should be the same as the file. Can I do it with some linux commands? Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i '1 { h; s/[^\t]//g; s/^/ID/; p; g; }' *.tsv
```

Copy the first line, remove all non-tabs (to clear the field contents), tack on "ID", then print this line plus the original.

Answer (score 2):

```
for file in *
do
   awk 'NR==1{hdr=$0; gsub(/[^\t]/,"",hdr); print "ID" hdr}1' "$file" > tmp &&
   mv tmp "$file"
done
```